# Stopping an NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer

Hi I am trying to stop an NSTimer by using "invalidate" however from everything that I have tried I cant seem to get the timer to stop.  Here is the code that I have to make this work.  I am trying to stop the timer from a different class.

My Timer

```
_tripTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel:)
                                            userInfo:[NSDate date]
                                            repeats:YES];
```

which is synthesized and is strong

and the stopping method:

```
-(void)stopTimer
{
    [_tripTimer invalidate];
}
```

and in my other class to get it to stop I am doing this:

```
  [_carTripViewController stopTimer];
```

however that is not working.  It is performing the method but not stopping the timer.  Im not sure if i am creating a new instance and that is why it is not working.  How can I get it to invalidate from another class?

Thank you!  I am fairly new to objective-c and not sure how to access it

Comment: You probably are instantiating a new class instead of getting a reference to the one you already have. Post the code to show how you create that instance.

Comment: Also, where is the first block of code being run? In -init or somewhere else? It's possible you are overwriting your _tripTimer ivar.

Answer (score 2):

In the docoumentation about the [invalidate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) Apple says:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> You must send this message *from the thread on which the timer was
>   installed*. If you send this message from another thread, the input
>   source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop,
>   which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.

If you create the thread in the main method you can stop it in the main method by calling:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) 
    withObject:anObj waitUntilDone:YES];
```

in your case something like:

```
[_carTripViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopTimer:) 
    withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two most probable causes:

1) You send `stopTimer` message to a different object of your class, not the one which where the timer has been launched.

2)  `_tripTimer` variable doesn't point to the timer object any more, it points to somewhere else, probably to nil.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what I did was to add the timer to my appDelegade and use that as my timer context. Im not sure if this is academically 100% correct, but it works for me and is a workable hack at least. So far I haven't run into any problems and my app has been used extensively. See my code example:

```
if (!self.pollerTimer) {
    self.pollerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:POLLER_INTERVAL
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(performPollinginBackground)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];

    //adds the timer variable and associated thread to the appDelegade. Remember to add a NSTimer property to your appDeledade.h, in this case its the pollerTimer variable as seen
    NUAppDelegate *appDelegate = (NUAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.pollerTimer = self.pollerTimer;
}
```

Then when I want to stop the timer from anywhere in my app I can do the following:

```
NUAppDelegate *appDelegate = (NUAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (appDelegate.pollerTimer) {
    [appDelegate.pollerTimer invalidate];
    appDelegate.pollerTimer = nil;
}
```